# Como emitir eventos de socket-io dentro de un endpoint

Tags: nodejs, typescript, socket.io

Mi intención es buscar una manera de poder manejar los eventos `on`, `emit`, etc. de socket, dentro de un endpoint.

Mi archivo index tiene esto:

Index.ts

```
import express, { Application } from 'express'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import HTTP from 'http'
import { Server } from 'socket.io'
import cors from 'cors'
import helmet from 'helmet'
import compression from 'compression'
import passport from 'passport'
import { config } from 'dotenv'
import './database/connect'
import passportAuth from './auth/passport'

//routers
import Authentication from './routers/authentication.routes'

class Backend {
  private app: Application
  private HTTP: HTTP.Server
  private io: Server

  constructor(){
    this.app = express()
    this.HTTP = HTTP.createServer(this.app)
    this.io = new Server(this.http)
    this._Config()
    this._Routers()
    config()
  }

  private _Config(): void {
    // Settings
    this.app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
    // middlewares
    this.app.use(morgan('dev'));
    this.app.use(cors());
    this.app.use(express.json());
    this.app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    this.app.use(passport.initialize());
    this.app.use(helmet());
    this.app.use(compression());
  }

  private _Routers(): void {
    //ruta estatica
    this.app.use("/uploads", express.static('./uploads'))
    //end-points y controladores
    this.app.use("/api", Authentication)
  }

  public _Start(): void {
    this.http.listen(this.app.get('port'), () => {
      console.log('Servidor escuchando en el puerto', this.app.get('port'))
    })

    this.io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
      console.log(socket.id)
    })
  }
}

const server = new Backend()
server._Start()
```

Como pueden ver, estoy escuchando la conexión al `socket` en el método `_Start()`. Lo que yo quiero hacer es poder manipular el parámetro que recibo (`socket`) de la función del `on` que es donde escucho la conexión al servidor.

Dentro de una carpeta `routers` manejo las rutas de la siguiente manera:

routers/authentication.routes.ts

```
import { Router } from 'express'
const route = Router()

//controllers
import { Iniciar_Sesion, Registrar } from './../controllers/authentication.controllers'

route.post('/iniciar', Iniciar_Sesion)
route.post('/registrar', Registrar)

export default route
```

Y como es obvio, dentro de otra carpeta contengo los controladores para tener mas ordenado mi código. Simplificando la pregunta, necesito poder emitir y escuchar eventos de los `sockets` dentro de cada endpoint.

> **PD:** Necesito que la conexión del socket no se reinicie cada vez que el usuario realice una petición, ya que guardo el id del socket dentro de la bbdd cada vez que el usuario inicia sesión y no es buena idea estar ingresando un nuevo id a la bbdd cuando el usuario haga una consulta al servidor, es por eso que hago la escucha `connection` dentro del `_Start()`

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es poder tener acceso al objeto `socket` (creado previamente en `_Start()`) dentro de la función `Iniciar_Sesion` de tu archivo `routers/authentication.routes.ts`?

Comment: mi idea es poder extender el objeto `req` de los controladores para poder utilizar desde alli el objeto `socket`, algo como `req.socket.emit()` o `req.socket.on()`, me explico?

Comment: en la pregunta agregue las rutas de auth para que tengan un ejemplo mas o menos de como esta estructurado el backend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Disclaimer

Supongo que no hay algo nativo ya implementado porque es un poco raro el caso que planteas, lo normal sería utilizar [namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/v3/namespaces/) o rooms. Sin embargo, supongo que podrían existir casos remotos donde sea necesario hacer algo como lo que quieres.

Antes de utilizar la siguiente solución, o alguna similar, contemple la opción de utilizar *namespaces* o *rooms*, pues es la forma más fácil (e integrada en la librería) de separar la lógica de la aplicación de WebSockets, así como separamos la lógica en la aplicación HTTP.

En palabras cortas el disclaimer es **preferir utilizar *namespaces* o *rooms* a utilizar esta solución** (es más sencillo)

## Solución

Dado que el protocolo HTTP es un protocolo [stateless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol), es un poco dificil hacer lo que se plantea, aunado a ello, se desea mantener un estado entre la aplicación que usa HTTP y la que usa websockets. En fin, después de entender el problema y analizarlo llegué a una posible solución que consiste en:

**Colocar el ID del socket en un header HTTP para que desde la ruta HTTP que quieras puedas acceder al objeto socket creado previemente (supuestamente).**

Para ello hice el siguiente ejemplo

### Código del server

> app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use("/", express.static("../web")); // ignorar esto

const io = require("socket.io")(3000); // poner el servidor de socket.io en el puerto 3000

const authRouter = require("./routers/auth.routers");

/**
 * Utilizar esta función como middleware para inyectar en el objeto req
 * el socket (de socket.io) correspondiente al header que exista en el objeto req
 * Si no se encuentra el socket, i. e. el cliente está haciendo una petición sin haber
 * iniciado una conexión con socket.io
 * entonces se inyectará un valor falsy en la propiedad {@code socketIO},
 * de lo contrario se inyectara el socket encontrado
 */
const injectSocketMiddleWare = (req, res, next) => {
    const socketID = req.header("X-Socket-IO-ID");
    const socketIO = io.of("/").sockets.get(socketID);

    if (!socketIO)
        console.warn("Some client does not have the X-Socket-IO-ID set!");

    req.socketIO = socketIO;

    next();
}

// utilizar el middleware para inyectar el socket en req.socketIO
app.use("/api", injectSocketMiddleWare, authRouter);

app.listen(3030, () => console.log("Server is listening"));
```

Nótese que hay un servidor a la escucha en el puerto `3030` (para las peticiones a `/api`) y otro en el puerto `3000` (para socket.io)

> routers/auth.routers.js

```
const Router = require("express").Router;

const router = Router();

router.post("/iniciar", (req, res) => {
    // verificar que el socket existe para que no truene el programa
    // nota: también hay que validar que emit sea una función, solo por si acaso
    if (req.socketIO && req.socketIO.emit)
        req.socketIO.emit("message", "Hola, este es un mensaje enviado desde el server para el cliente: " + req.socketIO.id);

    res.send();
});

module.exports = router;
```

El código con sus comentarios creo que se explica sólo y no hay necesidad de agregar mayor explicación, salvo por responder la pregunta ¿de dónde sale el header **X-Socket-IO-ID**?

Bueno, ese header como su nombre lo indica es el ID del `socket` generado, es el id del que vendría siendo el objeto `socket` dentro de la función callback para `this.io.on('connection', (socket)=>{...})` de la pregunta

Con ese ID podemos obtener el socket, gracias a que socket.io mantiene un hashtable (específicamente un `Map`) de los sockets conectados en un determinado *namespace* (con `io.of("/").sockets` obtenemos dicho `Map` para el *namespace* por defecto).

### Código del cliente

Con el servidor listo, solamente falta el código del cliente para agregar el header correspondiente, pero eso es más sencillo que lo anterior, el código simplemente es el siguiente.

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000"); // hacer la conexión con el servidor de socket.io

let socketID;

socket.on("connect", () => {
    socketID = socket.id;

    // hacer la petición al servidor de la API
    fetch("http://localhost:3030/api/iniciar", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "X-Socket-IO-ID": socketID // setear el header con el socket id correcto
    });
});

socket.on("message", (msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

Y listo, si se ejecuta el código anterior (backend y frontend) en la consola del frontend se debería ver el mensaje

```
Hola, este es un mensaje enviado desde el server para el cliente: <id del socket>
```

Por último, el manejo del ID del socket **quizá sea más sencillo si en vez de colocar un nuevo header, aprovechamos la sesión** y utilizamos [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) o alguno otro similar.

Aunque a final de cuentas esa forma de hacerlo es muy similar a la que está expuesta pues básicamente las sesiones se envían en los headers HTTP.

Ah, se me olvidaba aclarar que lo hice en javascript y no en typescript debido a que al agregar la propiedad `socketIO`, el compilador detectaba que algo andaba mal pues la interfaz `express.Request` no tiene ningún atributo `socketIO`, lo cual es totalmente cierto. Si se quisiera hacer en typescript habría que hacer una nueva clase o interfaz que incorporara dicho campo. Pero bueno, en general dejé la estructura del código presentado similar a la estructura del código de la pregunta.

Comment: me hablas de namespace o rooms, pero lo que quiero hacer es simplemente hacer las peticiones al backend y si esta todo bien entonces ejecuto los eventos del socket, ejemplo: un usuario comienza a seguir a otro, entonces hago todo el proceso y una vez guarde los datos donde deben ir emito el evento para avisarle al otro usuario que tiene un nuevo seguidor, me explico?

Comment: *me hablas de namespace o rooms, pero lo que quiero hacer es simplemente hacer las peticiones al backend y si esta todo bien entonces ejecuto los eventos del socket* -> Genial, pero las peticiones son ***STATELESS***, es decir ***NO GUARDAN INFORMACIÓN DE UNA VEZ PARA OTRA***. Cómo pretendes mantener entonces el socket entre llamadas?? Pues exactamente como se indica en esta respuesta, por ejemplo!

Comment: Exacto, como dijo Benito-B, así se puede "mantener" el estado (el socket) entre petición y petición. Realmente es el servidor el que tiene los sockets, los clientes solo mantienen una "referencia" (el ID) al socket. Lo que deseas hacer @enzo, lo puedes hacer con lo explicado en la respuesta, solo tienes que manejar un mapeo de usuarios, de forma similar a como se maneja el mapeo de sockets. Pero nuevamente, quizá sea mejor idea utilizar *namespaces* (por ejemplo, un namespace **/user** donde vayan todos los eventos del usuario, e.g. login, follow, etc... todo lo que quieras).